# hibernate jpa caches automatically / rest

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am not sure if the problem is actually caused by hibernate caching or if it's something completely else.

I have a rest webservice with the endpoints **/customers** and **/customers/:id**

Now when I send a delete-request to the endpoint **/customers/2**, the customer with id 2 gets deleted from the db but it still shows the customer when i send a get request to **/customers/2**. 
The weird thing is: the customer is removed from the customer list when requesting all customers to the endpoint **/customers**.

I believe that for some reason hibernate caches the customer but I am not sure. I hope someone can help.

```
public class Database {
private static EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();


public static List<? extends Model> all(Class<? extends Model> model) {
    List<? extends Model> list = entityManager.createQuery("from " + model.getName(), model).getResultList();
    return list;
}

public static Model find(Class<? extends Model> model, int id) {
    Model m = entityManager.find(model, id);
    return m;
}

}
```

***Customer class***

```
@Path("customers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerResource { 
@GET
public List<Customer> getCustomers(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
    List<Customer> customers = Customer.all();
    return customers;
}
@Path("{customerId}")
@GET
public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") int id, @Context UriInfo uriInfo){
    Customer customer = Customer.find(id);
    if(customer == null)
        throw new DataNotFoundException("customer with id " +  id + " not found!");
    return customer;
}

@DELETE
@Path("{customerId}")
public Response deleteCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") int customerId){
    agencyManager.removeCustomer(customerId);
    return Response.status(204).build();
}
}
```

In the agencymanager class:

```
  public void removeCustomer(int customerId){
    Customer customer = Customer.find(customerId);
    customer.delete();
}
```

customer.delete() is basically the same as em.remove(customer)

/e:
I am using **POSTMAN** as rest-client to test the methods.

I also believe its a caching problem because when I restart tomcat **/customers/2** delievers no-content..as it should

```
public void delete() {
    EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(this) ? this : entityManager.merge(this));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: Post the delete method as well.

Comment: @RP- I edited the first post

Comment: How is this `customer.delete()` method getting the `EntityManager` to delete ? Also, are there any associations involved with `Customer`.

Comment: edited the fp again. the delete method is in a model class which customer class is extending from

Comment: An EntityManager is a short-lived, not thread-safe object. Its life-time is typically the same as the life-time of a database transaction. But you're creating an EntityManager once, store it in a static variable, use it from all your threads, and never close it. That can't work.

Comment: ah..so adding entityManager.close() at the end of all methods int he database class should fix it?

Comment: No. You should, for each transaction (i.e. REST API call), open an EM, start a transaction, do your job, commit the transaction, and close the EM.

Comment: okey, thank you for your help. I understand now. I declare and initialize the entitymanager within the methods. now it all works :)